# Using GAE local testing with Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am trying to use the local testing helpers provided by google app engine to unit test my app which uses objectify. However, some of the tests fail with the following message;

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'datastore_v3' or call 'Put()' was not found.
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:164)
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:162)
        at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$CumulativeAggregateFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:145)
        at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ResultAdapter.now(ResultAdapter.java:29)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultWrapper.translate(ResultWrapper.java:20)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultWrapper.translate(ResultWrapper.java:1)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultTranslator.nowUncached(ResultTranslator.java:21)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:27)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultWrapper.translate(ResultWrapper.java:20)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultWrapper.translate(ResultWrapper.java:1)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultTranslator.nowUncached(ResultTranslator.java:21)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:27)
```

Here is my code:

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
    new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(),
    new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig());

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
}

.....
//In class constructor
ObjectifyService.register(SomeClass.class);
.....
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
}

public void doTest {
    SomeClass value = ......
    ofy().save().entity(value).now(); //throws error
}
```

Here is my dependency tree:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava-collections:jar:r03:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava-annotations:jar:r03:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava-primitives:jar:r03:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.google.guava:guava-base:jar:r03:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.11.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.11.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:jar:4.0a4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:jar:1.0.10:runtime
[INFO] |  \- com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:jar:1.10.3-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-appengine:jar:1.10.1-beta:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-servlet:jar:1.10.1-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-servlet:jar:1.10.3-beta:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.10.3-beta:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.10.3-beta:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.2.0:compile
```

Any idea what I am missing or am doing wrong?

Comment: The reference to appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.7.1 when everything else is 1.7.2 looks suspicous.

Comment: I fixed the sdk jar version but still get the same error. It seems to happen to calls just after a namespace change and is intermittent i.e. different tests fail every time.

Answer (score 1):

I just reproduced this error and fixed it by adding the following dependencies :

```
    <!--
      GAE libraries for local testing as described here:
      http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/howto/unittesting.html
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I use a local maven property to reference the same gae version.
 hope this help
Regards

Comment: If you look at the Dependency tree those dependencies are already there. I eventually got past this error by moving the relevant dependencies higher up the pom file and hence higher in priority. There was a transitive dependency on an earlier version of the stubs which was causing my problem.